# Oracle user - read only to any tables

Tags: user, sqldeveloper

I'm trying to add a user with read-only permissions to all tables. The problem is that after connecting to the database by SQL Developer, the tables (empty tab) do not appear on this user. Select on tables only works after adding the schema name. for example, `schema_name.table_name`.

What I've done:

```
CREATE USER user IDENTIFIED BY pass;

GRANT CONNECT TO user;

GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to user;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO user;

GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE  TO user;
```

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should add also:

```
grant select any dictionary to user;
```

to give user permission to get from dictionaries the list of tables

ALso is possible to grant to this user privilege to read catalogs:

```
grant SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to user;
```